# I am working in Unity and my Punch and jump animations don't play fully. How can I fix my code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get my character to punch and jump. Jump works but the animation does not always play. Punch will either not play at all or it will freeze halfway through the animation. Here is my code below. I think the error is in the lines surrounding the StopPunch (I did not write those but found in another solution to a similar question). Is the code right and my error is in unity possibly? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playermovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public CharacterController2D controller;
    public Animator animator;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    bool jump = false;
    bool crouch = false;
    bool punch = false;
  

    void Update()
    {
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));
        
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = true;

        }else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = false;

        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Punch"))
        {
            punch = true;
            if (punch)
            {
                animator.SetBool("IsPunching", true);
                StartCoroutine(StopPunch(2.0));
            }
        } 
            void StopPunch (float waitTime)
        {
                yield WaitForSeconds (waitTime);
                animator.SetBool("IsPunching", false);
            }
        
        
    }
    
    

    public void OnLanding ()
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
    }

    public void OnCrouching (bool isCrouching)
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsCrouching", isCrouching);
    }
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Move our character
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
        jump = false;
        animator.SetBool("IsPunching", false);
       
    }
}
```

Comment: I think if you look at your animator, and the state transition leaving whatever state IsPunching = false is leaving, you can set some properties there like  if there is a timeout for the animation and if it is cancelable.

Comment: @Topher I'm not sure I follow. The state that IsPunching is leaving is AnyState

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the transition away from punching, in the inspector you should see settings as in the screenshot which should allow for animations completing.
I'm guessing you'll need to play with some of these settings.

[image: Unity animator transition options]